# Local session_start returns many warnings

Tags: php, session, warnings, mamp

newb working with sessons on my local machine with a MAMP Stack on a mac. I've attempted to google on the errors but I'm not able to find a means to resolve the warning other then turning the warnings off and thats no good, right?

I have a session folder which is exists in my MAMP root (Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sessions). I've checked the spelling and the pathing and everything is thus far correct. The file returns a session id of 56d13f8845f91c8d7437bf0e45d94e53 and it appears to be working, but i have all these annoying warning messages and hoping for some general guideance as I delve back into the wonderfully confusing world of PHP.

I did try the following sudu commands but it didn't resolve the error as hoped:
sudo mkdir -p /var/chroot/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/
sudo chmod 1777 /var/chroot/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/

List of warning messages and notices when I test the page:

Warning: session_start(): open(/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/sess_283ee1651e6074199d0126aaf50179fa, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 6

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:6) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 6

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:6) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 6
If you can read this, sessions are working!
Session ID is: 283ee1651e6074199d0126aaf50179fa

Warning: Unknown: open(/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/sess_283ee1651e6074199d0126aaf50179fa, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/MAMP/htdocs/sessions) in Unknown on line 0

CODE:

```
    ini_set('session.save_path','MAMP/htdocs/sessions'); //local

    session_start(); //must be declared before using any session data
    $_SESSION['test'] = "If you can read this, sessions are working!"; //create test session
    print $_SESSION['test'] . "<br>";
    print "Session ID is: ". session_id()."<br>";
```

This is all the code in teh file, it does start with ''

## --- The following is the revised code and errors after trying initial suggestions----

```
I notice the most interesting difference in the reander being with the first warning that now reads '/sessions//...'. I suddenly has two forward slashes. Line numbers change to reflect that the session_start(); is now online #3 of the script.

<?php
    ini_set('session.save_path','/sessions/');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test'] = "If you can read this, sessions are working!";
    print $_SESSION['test'] . "<br>";
    print "Session ID is: ". session_id()."<br>";
?>
```

Rendered results to screen were as followed:
Warning: session_start(): open(/sessions//sess_8b67c0ef027e3c8936196d21fba298b3, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 3

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:3) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 3

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:3) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php on line 3
If you can read this, sessions are working!
Session ID is: 8b67c0ef027e3c8936196d21fba298b3

Warning: Unknown: open(/sessions//sess_8b67c0ef027e3c8936196d21fba298b3, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/sessions/) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: headers already sent means there is some data is outputted to the screen before session initialisation

Comment: Might be a path issue. Try `ini_set('session.save_path','/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/');` or `ini_set('session.save_path','/htdocs/sessions');` or `ini_set('session.save_path','/htdocs/sessions/');` and make sure there's nothing above `session_start();` except `<?php ini_set...` and byte order mark (UTF-8) - See what you can get from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: I'm aware that that is what the error means, but there is nothing to output, no html tag or anything, you see the whole file, all six lines listed above. I'm very perplexed.

Comment: Also, I've seen many using `/Applications/MAMP/...` so try that path.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/sess_283ee1651e6074199d0126aaf50179fa,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php
>   on line 6

I suspect a permission error, as OSX might not have sufficient permissions to create/store the session data.

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:6)
>   in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php
>   on line 6

This is a typical error message. Usually caused by output before invoking the `session_start()`. Check for White spaces, or other output before invoking the method

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php:6)
>   in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/review/itc240f/a_070-adminer/sessionTest.php
>   on line 6 If you can read this, sessions are working! Session ID is:
>   283ee1651e6074199d0126aaf50179fa

Same as above

> Warning: Unknown:
>   open(/MAMP/htdocs/sessions/sess_283ee1651e6074199d0126aaf50179fa,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Relates to the first message, as the first message is thrown due to not being able to find/trace the correct session data folder. This is just a child message, sort out the parent and this will go

> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify
>   that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (/MAMP/htdocs/sessions) in Unknown on line 0

Another Child error, resolve the parent error message (check file permissions, check that the user that apache runs as has sufficient permissions to modify/read/execute the correct folders

Comment: I posted my revised attempt below my first attempt. Removed all white space i could find, the result is things seem to shift from line error on six to three, but it's still with the session_start(); I don't think there is any other output involved. I've checked permissions and the session folder is writeable. So i'm stumped.

Comment: @Chezshire Are you looking at the right folder? as it seems you have changed in your most recent update/revision. /sessions/?

Comment: I think i am. the session folder is sitting at the same level as the htdocs folder is which is the 'root' space I beleive. And my session is pointed at it I believe; I added back '/htdocs/sessions' to line two, and the double forward slash went away, but the warnings persist. I think that it's something to do with permissions and I don't have the right tool to properly sett 0700 permission set maybe?

Comment: I found the answer, which is that it was a pathing issue, and that MAMP wants/defines the path as follows: 'session.save_path','/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sessions'. I needed to add Applications/MAMP/ to my path.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue was pathing and how the home/root of the directory is determined by MAMP.  I edited my code like so and it worked:

```
<?php
     ini_set('session.save_path','/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sessions');
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['test'] = "If you can read this, sessions are working!";
     print $_SESSION['test'] . "<br>";
     print "Session ID is: ". session_id()."<br>";
?>
```

The key was realizing that everything had to be done from the Application folder itself, not from within the MAMP folder.